# How can i access my DI Container configuration file from somewhere?

Tags: php

This is just for educational purpose. 
I am trying to reach my container settings file.

have a container class that gets requested class' constructor parameters(for the moment).

**$container->register($className)** function pushes data into an array.

Here is my container settings(conf.php) file:

```
require_once("./app/central/layer/items.php");

$container = new App\Central\Layer\Items;

$container->register("BlaBla_1");
$container->register("BlaBla_2");
```

Purpose:
I want to integrate this configuration file to somewhere i can reach easily from every class.

I don't want to call again and again everytime i try to reach container. 
I tried something like this.

**$containerLoader->loadConfig();**

BUT the result is an `**empty**` array.(when i'm trying to call from somewhere on another class)

**It only works with:**

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once("./conf.php");

        // I GET BLABLA_1'S CONSTRUCTOR PARAMATERS WITHOUT ANY PROBLEM
        $container->get("BlaBla_1");


    }

    //other methods...
}
```

I want to know how can i reach my settings file without doing this. I think that i am doing this in a very wrong way i guess. Any implementation ideas?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, DI stands for dependency injection, so one way would be to inject your container into your classes that depend on it.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct($container)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Another common method is to make your container global or using a helper function:

```
function container()
{
    global $container;
    return $container;
}
```

Then you can access your container with the helper function `container()` anywhere in your application.  Since container will only have one instance and should be accessible app-wide, this is one of the few times I find globals acceptable.

In either case, your config file should be included, and your container should be defined, prior to instantiating any service class in the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Devon. I also tried these two method except assign my my container variable as global. I am going try it. :)